# Help explaining symbols as hash values in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, symbols

Total Ruby noob. I'm going through Zed Shaw's LRTHW, and I'm stuck on the Hash exercise. I can't make any sense of this code, and can't find anything on the web that looks like it.

```
cities = {'CA' => 'San Francisco', 'MI' => 'Detroit', 'FL' => 'Jacksonville'}

cities['NY'] = 'New York'
cities['OR'] = 'Portland'

def find_city (map, state)
  if map.include? state
    return map[state]
  else
    return "Not found."
  end
end

cities[:find] = method(:find_city)

while true
  print "State? (Enter to quit) "
  state = gets.chomp

  break if state.empty?

  puts cities[:find].call(cities, state)
end
```

Basically, I'm just stuck. I can't make the connection between how I type in a state and it returns the city. Any dumbed down explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This code does not look like it was written for clarity.  Maybe it was written to demonstrate some particular part of ruby, like the `method` method?  The `map` parameter should be renamed to hash.  There is no need to use `method`; Zed could have simply called `find_city` within his while loop.  If he really wanted to, he could add `find` as a Singleton method on the hash table, then you don't need the `map` parameter (just use self).

Comment: This would be a better question if you included proper citation of the website/book where you found the code and told us what is the first line of code that you do not understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here there are a hash (cities) with 3 pairs key => value

```
cities = {'CA' => 'San Francisco', 'MI' => 'Detroit', 'FL' => 'Jacksonville'}
```

You can access that values by the key:

```
puts cities['CA']  #=>  'San Francisco'
```

Now we add two new pairs.

```
cities['NY'] = 'New York'
cities['OR'] = 'Portland'
```

The whole hash will be:

```
p cities #=> {'CA' => 'San Francisco', 'MI' => 'Detroit', 'FL' => 'Jacksonville', 'NY' => 'New York', 'OR' => 'Portland'}
```

Now it's defined a method called `find_city`. It takes a hash and a key.

```
def find_city (map, state)
  # if hash has the key, return its value. (There are better ways to do it.)
  if map.include? state
    return map[state]
  else
    return "Not found."
  end
end
```

Here there is the worst piece of Ruby code I've ever seen.

```
cities[:find] = method(:find_city)
```

Ok, that code gets the method `find_city` and turns it into a `Method` object, which could be assigned to a variable. BUT, instead of using a normal local variable, it is stored in a value of the `cities` hash!

That object is similar to a method, but it's an object instead of a method, and it must be called with `call` (in Ruby 1.8.7).

I will use a variable called `my_meth` (it could be any name) to explain better.

```
# get the method find_city and turns it into an object assigned to my_meth
my_meth = method(:find_city)

while true
  print "State? (Enter to quit) "
  state = gets.chomp

  break if state.empty?

  # here we use find_city on the cities hash.
  puts my_meth.call(cities, state)
end

puts my_meth.class
```

But, instead to use a variable, the original code stored the `Method` object on the `cities` hash. So, cities will be:

```
cities[:find] = method(:find_city)
p cities #=> {'CA' => 'San Francisco', 'MI' => 'Detroit', 'FL' => 'Jacksonville', 'NY' => 'New York', 'OR' => 'Portland', :find => (the Method object)}
```

So, you can access the `find_city` thru `cities[:find].call`.

Comment: @pst You're right! I've edited my answer to correct it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A symbol represents itself, just as 0 represents 0 -- and a symbol is only equal to itself. (Consider that `:foo == "foo"` is false, so `hash[:foo]` can never refer to the `hash["foo"]` pair, even if both may evaluate to the same object).

So `cities[:find]` just doesn't make much sense and it confuses the data (hash mapping sates to a big city) with the operation on the data... it might as well be `cityFindFunction` instead. However, because using the method itself is fine (no need to convert to a Function here!), consider this simplification:

```
cities = {'CA' => 'San Francisco', 'MI' => 'Detroit', 'FL' => 'Jacksonville'}

def find_city (map, state)
  if map.include? state
    # if this hash contains the state, e.g. "CA" then
    # return a big city in the state
    return map[state]
  else
    # otherwise return a diagnostic message
    return "Not found."
  end
end

while true
  print "State? (Enter to quit) "
  state = gets.chomp

  break if state.empty?

  # this is a method invocation, no need for "call"!
  puts find_city(cities, state)
end
```

This could be further simplified with returning `nil` instead of "Not found." (let the caller deal with it) or using the default-value of a Hash. In any case, I hope that the above shows "the essence" of what is being done.

Happy coding.

---

A brief bit on a method vs. Method vs Function.

In Ruby, methods are *not* first class values. Rather, they are "messages" that a given object reacts to. The `find_city(cities, state)` *method invocation* above is convenience for `self.__send__(:find_city, cities, state)`. (Well, not really because `__send__` is itself a method call, but that's the gist of what happens internally... ;-)

*Functions* (of type [Proc](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Proc.html)) and objects of type [*Method*](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Method.html), on the other hand, are just objects. As such, unlike *methods*, they are "first-class values". To *invoke/apply* a *Function/Method object*, use the `call` *method* (of the *Function/Method*) which executes the function with the given parameters and evaluates to the *Functions/Methods* return value.

The [`method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001038) *method* returns a *Method object* -- *bound to the instance of the object `method` was invoked upon* -- for a given *method*.

Hope that explains the rest somewhat ;-)

Comment: Wow, I can't believe how much this helped! Thanks so much.

Comment: I think I almost have it all sorted out in my head, your answer really helped. Can you just explain what exactly the "map" argument on the find_city method is doing? I'm not sure if I'm making the connection how the method is pulling the values from the cities hash.

Comment: @anatomyofashane The `map` variable inside the function corresponds to the `cities` Hash: the *Hash object* containing the states/cities, which was the result of evaluating the `cities` variable, at time of method invocation, is assigned to the `map` function parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Its not that hard.

- The first 4 lines fill your hash with abbreviation => name of state
- Then you define a method find_city that gets a map and an abbreviation and prints the corresponding name.
- Afterwards you put the method with the name find_city in the hash cities with the key :find.
- cities[:find].call(cities, state) just calls the previously saved method with the arguments.

Instead of using symbols here you could have used Strings or Integers at least for the hash part. Furthermore you could have used method("find_city") instead of method(:find_city)

You just have to understand basic ruby logic and that you can reference Methods as Objects.